# Is the position of "rather" interchangeable?

Tags: grammar

> He is not satisfied with her praise. He is **rather** satisfied with my praise.

I am sure this "rather" modifies "with my praise."
But the position of it doesn't have to be in front of "with?"
Like only, as in "You only clean your room when it gets helplessly untidy."

Comment: Why can't i get the question? Hence the up vote by me...

Comment: I was having trouble even understanding what the question being asked was.  Jon Hanna's answer is the only reason I can understand it (and even then, I have to assume that Jon Hanna is answering what the intended question was).

Comment: Please edit the question; it is unclear. (Maybe it should be moved to http://ell.stackexchange.com/?)

Answer (score 8):

> I am sure this "rather" modifies "with my praise."

You're wrong, it modifies *satisfied*. It's a vague quantifier, and its vagueness argues against its use, though it is popular in some communities.

> But the position of it doesn't have to be in front of "with?"

If you put it there, it is a completely different meaning of the word.

> He is surprised, rather, with my praise.

In this sense, *rather* indicates a contradiction, that contrasts it with the previous statement. Here it is modifying the whole phrase *he is satisfied with my phrase*.

Edit:

You could also have:

> He is, rather, satisfied with my praise.

The commas make this the sense of *rather* that applies to the whole sentence and hence contradicts the previous sentence. Hanging on a comma like that would be a bad idea when you could rephrase, as it increases the risk of mis-reading.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: In this case, my thinking is still wrong?

Comment: Yes, my answer still stands' *satisfied* has the same grammatical rôle as *surprised* in your original version.

Comment: I do think so, Because "Because, "He is not satisfied with her praise, rather with my praise." is the **not** same as the example. That sentence is more ambiguous and could be interpreted as either sense of *rather* I give above, though I'd read it as akin to the last example I give.

Comment: My dictionaries suggest no controversy.

Comment: The only controversy is whether using 'rather' in such a way that people can't make up their minds whether the pragmatic marker sense, the downtoner, or the intensifier sense is intended should be labelled 'poor' or 'ungrammatical'.

Comment: @birdman1234 why bother asking the question if you're just going to argue that the answer is wrong and you think you already know what's right?  I agree with Jon Hanna on this.

Answer (score 6):

"Rather" in your example isn't used to modify "with my praise", it modifies "satisfied". In this case it's used to indicate that the amount of satisfaction is different from just saying "He is satisfied with my praise".

Comment: Yes, but this is the downtoner rather than the (old-fashioned) intensifier usage of _rather_. _It's rather late_ v _She's rather super!_

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Agreed; I corrected the mistake in my original answer where I said "increase" rather than "indicate".

Comment: Also, quantifiers 'go before' (the term 'modify' here is perhaps ill-defined) noun groups ('In grammar, a quantifier is a type of determiner' / 'A determiner is a word, phrase or affix that occurs together with a noun or noun phrase' [Wikipedia]). 'Rather' is not a quantifier. I also wouldn't call intensifiers and downtoners 'adverbs' as some do. 'Degree ...' or 'secondary modifiers' (the latter allowing semantically-laden -ly forms like worryingly, suspiciously) can be used, provided we accept that 'modify' can be used for the 'modifying' of adjectives and adverbs.